# Sencha Touch ajax prefilter, supply url root for all ajax requests

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In a Sencha touch aplication, can I use some sort of ajax prefilter and supply a URL root for all my requests (from stores and models)?

One more thing,

Is there a way to add a AUTH-TOKEN header, alto to every ajax request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext.Ajax.request is a singleton instance.  You can tap on beforerequest event and change/modify url, add/remove headers and do all other modification as needed.  This way you can capture all your ajax request.  You should be able to do this in your app.launch function.

```
 Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function(conn, request, eOpts){
      // Your implementaion here.  change request.url, request.headers etc
 });
```

Comment: I have a launch function and from there a router - I'll test it... super.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the URL on your store proxies via [Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.url](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-url), you could do this in one of two ways.

One: you can extend (or override) the class, adding the logic yourself.

Two: you could configure your URLs as such:

```
//someplace define this...
var urlPrefix = function() {
    return '/path/to/API/';
};

//in your store/proxy
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Foo', {
    config : {
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url  : urlPrefix() + 'API_endpoint'
        }
    }
});
```

I've done that a bunch of times before.

As for your Auth headers, you can override [Ext.data.Connection](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection) to include additional headers. The key here is that you would need to override it very early in the application lifetime, because other classes have unique instances of *Ext.data.Connection* (for example, Ext.Ajax).

But before giving a recommendation on how to apply the headers globally, I'd need to know more about what you needed to do. There's many things to consider before doing that.